# How to get rid of this ??? "The following classes could not be instantiated"

Tags: android, dynamic, view

This is the my XML file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bgcategory"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/topbar" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_back" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img_share">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_audio_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_share"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_share"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_back"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#fffafa"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.example.activities.VisualizerView
            android:id="@+id/visualizerView_scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip">
        </com.example.activities.VisualizerView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/visualizerView_scroll"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
        </SeekBar>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/new_play" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play_scroll"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/play_scroll"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/new_pause" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play_scroll"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play_scroll"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/new_stop" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llCommentContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/play_scroll">
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llCommentContainer"> 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_addcomment">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the class ::

```
public class VisualizerView extends View 
{
private static final String TAG = "VisualizerView";

private byte[] mBytes;
private byte[] mFFTBytes;
private Rect mRect = new Rect();
private Visualizer mVisualizer;

private Set<Renderer> mRenderers;

private Paint mFlashPaint = new Paint();
private Paint mFadePaint = new Paint();

public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public VisualizerView(Context context)
{
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public void init() 
{
    mBytes = null;
    mFFTBytes = null;

    mFlashPaint.setColor(Color.argb(122, 255, 255, 255));
    mFadePaint.setColor(Color.argb(238, 255, 255, 255)); // Adjust alpha to change how quickly the image fades
    mFadePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));

    mRenderers = new HashSet<Renderer>();
}

/**
 * Links the visualizer to a player
 * @param player - MediaPlayer instance to link to
 */
public void link(MediaPlayer player)
{
    if(player == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot link to null MediaPlayer");
    }

    // Create the Visualizer object and attach it to our media player.
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(player.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);

    // Pass through Visualizer data to VisualizerView
    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
    {
        //@Override
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,int samplingRate)
        {
            updateVisualizer(bytes);
        }
        //@Override
        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,int samplingRate)
        {
            updateVisualizerFFT(bytes);
        }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
            Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, true);

    // Enabled Visualizer and disable when we're done with the stream
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        //@Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
        {
            mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}

public void addRenderer(Renderer renderer)
{
    if(renderer != null)
    {
        mRenderers.add(renderer);
    }
}

public void clearRenderers()
{
    mRenderers.clear();
}

/**
 * Call to release the resources used by VisualizerView. Like with the
 * MediaPlayer it is good practice to call this method
 */
public void release()
{
    mVisualizer.release();
}

/**
 * Pass data to the visualizer. Typically this will be obtained from the
 * Android Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener call back. See
 * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onWaveFormDataCapture }
 * @param bytes
 */
public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
    mBytes = bytes;
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Pass FFT data to the visualizer. Typically this will be obtained from the
 * Android Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener call back. See
 * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onFftDataCapture }
 * @param bytes
 */
public void updateVisualizerFFT(byte[] bytes) {
    mFFTBytes = bytes;
    invalidate();
}

boolean mFlash = false;

/**
 * Call this to make the visualizer flash. Useful for flashing at the start
 * of a song/loop etc...
 */
public void flash() {
    mFlash = true;
    invalidate();
}

Bitmap mCanvasBitmap;
Canvas mCanvas;


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Create canvas once we're ready to draw
    mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    if(mCanvasBitmap == null)
    {
        mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    if(mCanvas == null)
    {
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mCanvasBitmap);
    }

    if (mBytes != null) {
        // Render all audio renderers
        AudioData audioData = new AudioData(mBytes);
        for(Renderer r : mRenderers)
        {
            r.render(mCanvas, audioData, mRect);
        }
    }

    if (mFFTBytes != null) {
        // Render all FFT renderers
        FFTData fftData = new FFTData(mFFTBytes);
        for(Renderer r : mRenderers)
        {
            r.render(mCanvas, fftData, mRect);
        }
    }

    // Fade out old contents
    mCanvas.drawPaint(mFadePaint);

    if(mFlash)
    {
        mFlash = false;
        mCanvas.drawPaint(mFlashPaint);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mCanvasBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
}
}
```

My Error Log :::

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.media.audiofx.Visualizer$OnDataCaptureListener
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:327)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:166)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:711)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:711)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:711)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:321)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:322)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1640)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1391)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1165)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:679)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1730)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Now I am trying to use this visualizer view when user click on the play button.
But in my graphical layout of the file i am getting this message that "The following classes could not be instantiated" also i am not able to show the my imageview(i.e. imgComment) in the view.Any suggestions that where i am wrong???

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Can you tell us which class could not be instantiated (second line of your error message) ? Also, a copy of your log window may be useful. Last, your layout has some errors (an empty and useless LinearLayout, a @layout_below attribute refering to another view which is in a different RelativeLayout parent, and maybe others...)

Comment: @Orabig i have edited my question ..plz have a look at it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with my code. After putting out any reference to the Android Visualizer calss from my custom view and putting it to my activity class everything was fine again. (Basically this is what Orabîg recomended in his response, but I'm not able to comment on it.)

However is this a bug that should be reported to ADT?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom View (com.example.activities.VisualizerView) fail to load in Eclipse because of a "ClassNotFound" exception.
I guess that the Eclipse layout viewer plugin does not include the android.media.audiofx package...

Maybe can you try to externalize this code (the link() method) in a separate class to see if Eclipse is happier and able to successfully load this class ?